# Populate table view from different Swift file

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am having Search view Controller:

[Refer This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nczD.png) .

In this image you can see it has tableview, search_textfiled and advance search button. So if I put some text in search field and click on search icon it use to fire query and it is populating the result in the table. But when clicking on Advance search it use to open one popover, which is having some text_field.

[Refer this image for Popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DQva.png).

So after entering value in all fields I have to do search and fire query and populate table view present in Search view controller. So when clicking on search I am calling that full_text_search function which use to fire query and populate data in table view. So in popover controller creating instance of search controller and calling search function but it is showing thread exception.

```
    func full_text_search(){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
        image_contain.removeAll()
        datafiles.removeAll()
        search_table.reloadData()
        search_table.delegate = self
        search_table.dataSource = self
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let username = defaults.string(forKey: "username")
        let password = defaults.string(forKey: "password")
        
        var check_icon_flag = 0
        let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", username!, password!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()
        let serarchbar_text = search_text.text
        print(serarchbar_text)
        var new_String = "http://xx.xxxx.com:9090/dtm-rest/repositories/xxx/search?q='"
      new_String.append(serarchbar_text!+"'&object-type=dm_document")
    
        

     let again_new_String =  new_String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        let url = URL(string: again_new_String!)
        print(again_new_String)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

##After this use to fetch query result and at last i use refresh table data
```

So in above code it use to show thread exception in

> search_table.reloadData
>
> search_table.delegate = self
>
> search_table.dataSource = self

If I call this function from search controller it is working fine. This function is defined in search controller only.But calling from popover controller it is giving exception.Below function shows calling full_text_search function from popover view controller.

```
  @IBAction func Search(_ sender: Any) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        print("2sec")
        let check_search = SearchViewController()
        check_search.full_text_search()
    }
   removeAnimate()
}
```

What to do if I want to add some values to query using popover view and then do search.

How I am calling popover :

```
 @IBAction func advance_search(_ sender: Any) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "types_popover") as! TypesViewController
   
    
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
  
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but first you need just one SearchViewController. You don't need to create it evеry time. After that you have to set the delegate and dataSource only once not on every search. And then your SearchViewController can be delegate of the Popover. Like this you can store values from the poppever fields in the SearchViewController and after that to reload the data in the SearchViewController.

Comment: @m1sh0 So where i can put that delegate and data source . If i use to put in view didload again it use to give error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". can you give some solution how to write?

Comment: It is hard to give you the exact code but: First on viewDidLoad chech if these two are initialized image_contain, datafiles. After that you should show me how you display the popover. But in general the idea is that you have to pass your SerchViewController as delegate to the Popover class. In a same way as you pas SearchViewController as delegate to the TableView

Comment: @m1sh0 Check I have edited post (Displaying popover), I am very new to this thing like how to pass my SearchViewController as delegate to the popover class.

Comment: Okay, first check delegate pattern here https://theswiftdev.com/2018/06/27/swift-delegate-design-pattern/ then you need to create protocol PopoverDataDelegate with methods for setDataNumber, setTitle and etc. This protocol will be implemented from your SerchViewController. Then popOverVC.delegate = searchViewController. And in the popOverVC class you can do self.delegate.setTitle() wich will set advanced search title in the searchViewController. In the end you will need just to relaod the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of populating the tableView from another VC, use delegates to populate it in its own VC, read more about delegates

> [Here](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)

so inside the popover VC, you pass the parameters you required for search and fire up a function inside the tableview VC, and perform the searching pretty simple

in your case the delegate protocol function should hold all the required search parameters

Comment: if you want some code to, tell me i can edit and provide but i think if you read about delegates and learn how to implement them, this would solve a lot of time for you in the future and solves a lot of cases too